# Is alkyl bromide or alkyl chloride formed when alcohol reacts with thionyl bromide or thionyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry

Would alkyl bromide/alkyl chloride form when an alcohol reacts with thionyl bromide/thionyl chloride?

Comment: Did you not mean chloride instead of iodide? Or perhaps other way round... 'cause right now it makes no sense. Even then you should have some reason to think why not.

Answer (score 2):

Thionyl chloride is a standard reagent for the conversion of alkyl alcohols to alkyl chlorides. [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thionyl_chloride).

Thionyl bromide converts alkyl chlorides to alkyl bromides but is less used as it is less widely available and less stable, thus more difficult to store. [more details](http://www.commonorganicchemistry.com/Common_Reagents/Thionyl_Bromide/Thionyl_Bromide.htm)